# Sum accesses for single user and know what type of access using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to sum of accesses per single user and know what type of access was performed the previous day

The type of access is of three types

1. B
2. L
3. T

This is mytable MySQL 5.1.51-community version

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_access`;
CREATE TABLE `tbl_access`  (
  `xUserCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xDate` date NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `xCl` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `xTypeAccess` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xNrUserCode` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `xID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`xID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of tbl_access
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `tbl_access` VALUES ('620', '2021-01-07', 5276, 'B', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO `tbl_access` VALUES ('620', '2021-01-07', 23613, 'B', 1, 2);
INSERT INTO `tbl_access` VALUES ('620', '2021-01-07', 36278, 'L', 1, 3);
```

I need this return

```
+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| xUserCode | xNrUserCode | xCl    | xTypeAccess |
+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| 620       | 3           | 65.167 | B+B+L       |
+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+
```

And I have tried this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    xUserCode,
    SUM( xNrUserCode ) AS xNrUserCode,
    REPLACE ( FORMAT( IFNULL( SUM( xCl ), 0 ), 0 ), ',', '.' ) AS xCl,
CASE            
        WHEN xTypeAccess= 'B' THEN
        'B' 
        WHEN xTypeAccess = 'L' THEN
        'L' 
        WHEN xTypeAccess = 'T' THEN
        'T' ELSE NULL 
    END AS xTypeAccess 
FROM
    tbl_access 
WHERE
    xDate = DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY ) 
    AND xUserCode = '620';
```

But the return is

```
+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| xUserCode | xNrUserCode | xCl    | xTypeAccess |
+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| 620       | 3           | 65.167 | B           |
+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+
```

How to do resolve this?

Comment: Your data set is too small to be representative. That said, seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(xTypeAccess SEPARATOR '+')
```

So your query will be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    xUserCode,
    SUM( xNrUserCode ) AS xNrUserCode,
    REPLACE ( FORMAT( IFNULL( SUM( xCl ), 0 ), 0 ), ',', '.' ) AS xCl,
    GROUP_CONCAT(xTypeAccess SEPARATOR '+')
FROM
    tbl_access 
WHERE
    xDate = DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY ) 
    AND xUserCode = '620';
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0800c4/6)

Note: I think there is no need for the case statement as long as `xTypeAccess` is of type `char` and its values are always in `('B', 'L', 'T')`

Comment: Similar solution here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-group_concat-function/